# Backwards stability of QR vs SVD

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I've been reading Trefethen & Bau's book on Numerical Linear Algebra, and they have this one question whose answer does not entirely make sense to me.  In particular, they imply that the SVD algorithm (the computation of the SVD, not the solution of $Ax = b$ by SVD) is not backwards stable.  The suggestion is that this has to do with the fact that SVD maps from an $m\times n$ matrix into the space of triples of $m\times m$, $m\times n$, and $n\times n$ for $U$, $\Sigma$, and $V$.  They have a comment, with regards to the outer product computation, that since that, too, maps from a smaller dimensional space into a larger one, the computation should not be expected to be backwards stable.  At the same time, Householder triangularization ($QR$), is backwards stable, but this too maps from a smaller dimensional space into a larger dimensional space.  Is Householder just an exceptional case, or is there more to this?

Answer (score 5):

Notice that there are restrictions on the output matrices. In QR factorization, Q(an orthogonal matrix) has dimension $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$, R(upper triangular matrix) has dimension $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, the total dimension is $n^2$, the dimension of n by n matrices.

Comment: If you throw your math symbols in between "$"s, it turns out prettier